# Use the same shortcut when Ctrl Key is pressed down in AutoHotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I have a basic keyboard with no multimedia keys. So I created a simple [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com) script to increase, decrease & mute my system volume:

```
^F10::Send {Volume_Mute}
^F11::Send {Volume_Down 5}
^F12::Send {Volume_Up 5}
```

The results are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> for Mute
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> for Volume Down
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for Volume Up

These shortcuts work fine. But the problem is when I press the <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> key for the second time (still holding the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key). Instead of invoking the given shortcut, only the keypress is executed; that is, only <kbd>F11</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> key.

How can I fix this ? Is there a better way to make the code better so it doesn't cause any problem while playing a game? It's sometimes problematic for me when using these shortcuts while in CS 1.6.

**EDIT :** The first shortcut (with <kbd>F10</kbd>) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem using **SendInput** instead of **Send**
. Here's the script now

```
^F10::SendInput {Volume_Mute}
^F11::SendInput {Volume_Down 5}
^F12::SendInput {Volume_Up 5}
```

But I still face some problems while using these in games (like in CS 1.6 the radio chat commands come up when I use this shortcut, though I can increase or decrease the volume while playing).

Comment: Bind your commands to some non-conflicting shortcuts, for example CapsLock+F1, CapsLock+F2, CapsLock+F3 (Or AppsKey + ...)  You can still preserve key's original functionality using `CapsLock::CapsLock`.